# Font needed for 30's comic strip

Tags: fonts, comics

Greetings from a beginner! I am part of a team trying to restore a 1930's newspaper comic strip for possible publication. We have to use newspaper scans, and the text is often very messy. It has to be retyped, in a font as close to this sample as possible. Several fonts have been used during the span of this comic, this being the most readable.

Can anyone point me to a suitable font? Scandinavian alphabets (å, ä, ö) are needed. The font doesn't have to be free. I understand that the exact font can't be found on digital form, and the sample here is distorted.

[image]

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/comiccl.jpg/

Comment: Are you looking to keep the 'patina' of the old printed then scanned type? If so, I may suggest making a custom font from the existing scans.

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is to check at http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/
as I did and the results were as follow:
Memorial-Regular
Tundra Pro Extlight
Penelope-Semi Bold
ITC Cheltenham Condensed Book
PF Centro Slab Pro Medium

IMO it's possible that exact type never to be digitized so you may try something similar.

Comment: I didn't even expect such a program to exist! Thanks a million.

Comment: I ended up using Century Schoolbook. Century was the closest match, and the Schoolbook variant with its stronger lines more readable in small size than the original. Thanks again for the help, here is another tool that I ended up using. This is good when the scanned material would be of too poor quality: http://www.identifont.com/identify.html

Comment: thanks for the tool and Century Schoolbook will suit nicely ;)